# Filtering my property in a getter

Tags: c#, .net, get, set, filtering

Here is my code:

```
private Analyst _PrimaryAnalyst;
public Analyst PrimaryAnalyst
{             
    get       
    {
        Analyst activeAnalysts;

        if (this.PrimaryAnalyst.IsActive == true)
        { 
            activeAnalysts = _PrimaryAnalyst;
        }

        return activeAnalysts; //"Use of unassigned local variable"               
    }         
    set
    {              
        SetPropertyValue("PrimaryAnalyst", ref _PrimaryAnalyst, value);                          
    }
}
```

Basically I am trying to filter my Analyst property based on if they are marked Active or not. Then I want to to return only Active Analysts. (Based on a bool property of Analyst), I am getting an error on the return statement saying "Use of unassigned local variable"

However I am clearly assigning it in the if statement?

Comment: Not all code paths lead to an assignment. You should initialize the variable before the `if`, or include an `else` and assign it to something else there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# you can not use a local variable before assigning it a value.

C# Language Specification, section 1.6.6.2

> C# requires a local variable to be definitely assigned before its
>   value can be obtained

lets get to your code

what happen if `this.PrimaryAnalyst.IsActive` is false? Yes, Use of unassigned local variable

you can fix this by initializing the local variable.

```
Analyst activeAnalysts = null;
```

or

```
if (this.PrimaryAnalyst.IsActive == true)
{ 
    activeAnalysts = _PrimaryAnalyst;
}
else
{
     activeAnalysts = null;
}
```

but there is another problem here. Your code leads to [StackOverflowException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx) because you are calling a method inside itself (recursion) but there is no way out of it so it leads to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)Exception
you should  change the line `this.PrimaryAnalyst.IsActive == true` to `_PrimaryAnalyst.IsActive == true`

Answer (score 2):

Change the first line of the getter to:

```
Analyst activeAnalysts = null;
```

The issue is that if the if statement evaluates to false, then the value is never set, so the compiler doesn't know what it should return.

Comment: Also your if clause will result in an infinite recursion, since it will keep calling the getter over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting the error is that not all code paths lead to an assignment. You should either initialize the variable before the `if`, or include an `else` and assign it to something there.

Also, you should be checking your private variable in the `if` statement instead of the public one (to avoid a `StackOverflowException`), and, assuming that `Analyst` is a nullable class, you should also ensure it's not null before checking `IsActive`. A property getter should not throw an exception.

Your getter can be also be simplified using a ternary assignment:

```
get
{
    return (_PrimaryAnalyst != null && _PrimaryAnalyst.IsActive) 
        ? _PrimaryAnalyst 
        : null;
}
```